# Is this snippet unnecessary in the source code of Arraylist.remove(int index)?

Tags: java, arraylist

Here's the source code:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).
>   Parameters:
>   index the index of the element to be removed
>   Returns:
>   the element that was removed from the list
>   Throws:
>   [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.java#IndexOutOfBoundsException)

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);
    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);
    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
        numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work
    return oldValue;
}
```

My question is:

As the [rangeCheck(index)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.rangeCheck%28int%29) has already guarantee that *index < size*, is it necessary to check that `if (numMoved > 0)`?

Answer (score 6):

`numMoved` can be 0 (if you remove the last element by calling `list.remove(list.size()-1)`), in which case no `arraycopy` is required. Therefore the `if (numMoved > 0)` is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

When you remove the last element of the list, `index` is equal to `size - 1`, in which case `numMoved` is 0 and no `System.arraycopy` is required.